# I'm trying to pull data from a variable into a jquery dialog without refreshingas

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm so new to this and not even sure if I'm describing what exactly I'm trying to accomplish here, but here it goes.

I have a table set in a variable and I would like it to display in a Jquery dialog box but I'm only able to when I refresh. Is there a way to load it once I click the button to open the dialog box?

I'm stuck and it's driving my bananas.

Thanks for any feedback.

Here's the basic code...

```
  $( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,

  });

  $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
  } );


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>#myVariable</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

............................................................

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fli</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


<style>

.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}
.ui-button {
      background-color:#1C2733;
      height:60px;
      width:200px;
      color:white;
      border-color:#1C2733;
      border-radius:0px;
  }
    .ui-button:active {
      background-color:#0E1F21;
      color:white;
  }
  .ui-button:hover {
      background-color:#0E1F21;
      border-color:#1C2733;
      color:white;
  }
  .ui-button:link {
      background-color:#0E1F21;
      color:white;
  }
  label {
      font-size:13px;
  }
  .button-SD {
    background-color: #FF3F00;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
   .button-SD:hover {
    background-color: #FB7005;
    color: white;   
}
#sd-search-form {
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin-left: -18px;
}
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:30px;
    font-size:12px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}input[type=checkbox] {
    font-size: 13px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    font-size:13px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
option {
    font-size: 13px;
}
input {
    font-size: 13px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  font-size: 13px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  font-size: 13px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  font-size: 13px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  font-size: 13px;
}
.ui-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  top: 62px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 287px;
}
#sdopener {
    background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") 50px center no-repeat;
    height:60px;
}
#sdopener:hover {
      background-color:#0E1F21;
      border-color:#1C2733;
      color:white;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    background-position: -80px -224px;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<!-- Navigation Buttons Start -->

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#1C2733; width:100%; height:60px; margin-top: -8px; margin-left: -8px; padding-right:16px">

<input name="SDSearchDialogOpener" type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="sdopener" style="margin-left:-18px" value="             SD Search">

<!-- SD Search Start -->

    <div id="sddialog" title="SD Search">

    <label for="sdkeyword">Seed Keyword(s):</label>
    <input type="text" id="TextBoxKW" placeholder="ie. iphone case" variable="#TextBoxKW">
    <br>

 <div class="ratings">
    <label for="rating">Rating:</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="TwoThumbs" name="Rating" fillwith="checked" variable="#TwoThumbs" />
    <span style="font-size: 13px"> 2+ Rating</span><br>
    <input type="radio" id="OneThumbs" name="Rating" fillwith="checked" variable="#OneThumbs" />
    <span style="font-size: 13px"> 1+ Rating</span><br>
    <input type="radio" id="ZeroThumbs" name="Rating" fillwith="checked" variable="#ZeroThumbs" />
    <span style="font-size: 13px"> 0 Rating</span><br>
    <input type="radio" id="AllThumbs" name="Rating" fillwith="checked" variable="#AllThumbs" />
    <span style="font-size: 13px"> All Ratings</span>
  </div>
    <br>

    <label for="price">Price:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="PriceLow" style="width:101px" placeholder="$ min" variable="#PriceLow"> -
    <input type="text" id="PriceHigh" style="width:101px" placeholder="$ max" variable="#PriceHigh">
    <br>

    <select id="DropDownDate" variable="#DropDownDate" style="font-size: 13px">
      <option value="Any Time"><span style="font-size: 13px">Any Time</span></option>
      <option value="Past Week"><span style="font-size: 13px">Past Week</span></option>
      <option value="Past 2 Weeks"><span style="font-size: 13px">Past 2 Weeks</span></option>
    </select>
    <br>


 <input class="button-SD" type="button" value="Search" id="sdopener2" onclick="ubot.runScript('ProductSearch()')" />
 </div>   
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
    <!--    <input class="button ButtonResults ButtonResultsinput" type="button" value="Return to results" id="ButtonResults" style="width:240px; visibility:hidden; height:20px" onclick="ubot.runScript('Back to Search Results()')" /> -->


<div id="sddialog2" title="Search Progress">


<input class="button-SD" type="button" value="View Search Results" id="sdopener3" style="width:300px;"  />
</div>

<div id="sddialog3" title="Search Results">
<div>HERE'S WHERE THE TABLE CHART VARIABLE WILL GO</div>
</div>



<!-- SD Search End -->



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );

$("#sdopener").click(function () {
    $("#sddialog").dialog("open");
});
$("#sddialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    position: [0,61],
    width: 289,
    height: 642,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog #sdopener2").click(function () {
            $("#sddialog2").dialog("open");
        });
    }
});

$("#sddialog2").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 335,
    height: 250,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog #sdopener3").click(function () {
            $("#sddialog3").dialog("open");
         });
    }
});

$("#sddialog3").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false,
    position: [298,61],
    width: '900',
    height: 642,
    resizable: true,
    handles: "all",
    autoHide:true
});

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of materials for this purpose, and the below link provide you the full functional and design with some clear examples.

[Jquery Modal](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)

Try this:

```
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,

  });

  $( "#opener" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  $("#content").html($("#tables").html());
  });
  } );


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p id="content">#myVariable</p>
</div>

<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>

<div style="display: none;" id="tables">
    Write here to show in modal...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, however I'm not sure what I'm looking for with the link you provided. Can you send me something more specific as to how to take a variable and upon clicking to open the dialog the content of that variable will display in the dialog box. It seems I have to refresh first in order for the variables content to display. Thanks.

Comment: Is your dialog appear when you click on link?

Comment: Yes the dialog appears but the variable data doesn't unless I refresh.

Comment: I edited the answer, please copy and paste my code and it will works

Comment: @Light please download and use from https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.modal link, this will works fine.